# Windows 8.1 People: every letter just brings up all contacts?

Tags: windows, windows-8, contacts, windows-8-people-app

Just updated to 8.1 from 8, and for some reason the People app, regardless of what letter you press, just shows all contacts every time.

So you press 'A', for example, and it just takes you to all contacts. (Furthermore, none of the letters are highlighted, which would be the expected convention to show which letters had contacts under them and which didn't. Not sure if this is related...)

Is this some weird bug, or just me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have already tried this, but try doing this:

1. If you're using a mouse, click the top of the app, and drag it towards the bottom (top image). *However*, do not let go of the mouse until the "tile" of the People app flips around and the People app icon appears (lower image). Then let go of the mouse to completely exit the People application.
   [image: Before Close] [image: After Close]
2. If you are using a touchscreen, tap and slide the app towards the bottom, and let go once the tile fips.
3. Restart the People app.

This worked for me just now. The key is to make sure the application is completely closed and reopened, not just pushed into the background. When Windows 8.1 was rleased, they changed the way to "hard exit" an application.

Comment: Will Alt+F4 still close the app outright?

Comment: Yes, however it took a couple seconds for it to close for me. If you are going to use `Alt+F4`, check your task manager to make sure it has quit completely

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I'm afraid. Tried your method, plus Alt+F4 (confirmed not running in task manager after) and even PC restart. After opening, same problem :(

Comment: Is your People application updated to the latest version?  In addition, are you using the search bar on the main screen, or in the charms bar?